# <tx:attributes> tag not allowed on intellij idea

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, config

the tag  is not allow on Intellij when I config spring transaction,and here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdivce" >
    <tx:attributes>

    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

<

Comment: change your `tx` namespace to `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"` and add to schemalocation `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd`.